# Ambiguous Magento 2 Structure

Tags: magento2

I am new in Magento Framework. Here I did found header.phtml, logo.phtml, header links etc. But i can't figure out how all these files are bind together? What holds these together? If i have to add another div where should I add? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

M2 structure is altogether different than M1. Depending upon what are you planning to do, I'd recommend creating a new file and linking it using the layout xml.

I hope it helps.